# Query optimisation - Boolean retrieval of conjunctive queries

Tags: query-optimization, theory, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I am taking an Information Retrieval course, where we have started with "Boolean retrieval".

I have come across the following question (taken from the [Stanford book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/contents-1.html) on Information retrieval):

> For a conjunctive query, is processing postings lists in order of size
>   guaranteed to be optimal? Explain why / why not.

The explanation given is as follows:

> The order is not guaranteed to be optimal. Consider three terms with
>   postings list sizes s1=100, s2=105 and s3=110. Suppose the
>   intersection of s1 and s2 has length 100 and the intersection of s1
>   and s3 length 0. The ordering s1, s2, s3 requires 100+105+100+110=315
>   steps through the postings lists. The ordering s1, s3, s2 requires
>   100+110+0+0=210 steps through the postings lists.

Could anyone please explain the above?

For instance: In "**100**+105+**100**+110"; what does 100 stand for? Is it the size of s1 or the intersection between s1 and s2? (105 and 110 are fairly obvious).

Answer (score 0):

According to the question,you should process the postings lists in **ascending order**(with size).Considering **s1** = 100,**s2** = 105,**s3** = 110.So you should process **s1** and **s2** first.Let's say you get **r1** = **s1** *AND* **s2**,then you should process **r1** and **s3**.
  [image]

According to the algorithm,you can estimate the consumption.

Since **s1** *AND* **s2** = **r1**,and **r1** has 100 length.Now the consumption is:  O(s1+s2) = 100 + 105 = 205,then you process **r1** with **s3**,the consumption is O(r1+s3) = 100 + 110 = 210,so the whole consumption is 205 + 210 = 415.

But we already know **s1** *AND* **s3** = 0,so we should process **s1** and **s3** first with consumption O(s1+s3) = 100+110 = 210,let's call it **r2**.Finally process **r2** and **s2**, O(r2+s2) = 0(since **r2** has 0 length).So the whole consumption is 210 + 0 = 210 which is smaller than 415.

The key idea is that we don't know the **intermediate result**(here stands for **r1** or **r2**).So processing postings lists in order of size may not guaranteed to be optimal.